# How to Combine 2 SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, combiners

I have a table like below picture:
[image]
Query 1:

```
Select  MIN(SaleStartDate) as MinSaleDate 
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 and (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0)
```

> > Result: 2017-02-10 (yyyy-MM-dd)

Query 2:

```
Select  MAX(SaleEndDate) as MaxSaleDate
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 and  (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleEndDate) < 0)
```

> > Result: 2017-01-02 (yyyy-MM-dd)

I want to show 2 results with only 1 query.
Please help me! Thank every body!

Comment: `select max(), min() ...`?

Comment: it return NULL. 2 where clause is difference, ande 2 result that I get is 2 result of 2 difference records :(

Comment: Do you need both results in one row or in different rows?

Comment: I want both results in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both results in one row:

```
Select  
(
Select  MIN(SaleStartDate) as MinSaleDate 
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 
and (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0)
),
(
Select  MAX(SaleEndDate) as MaxSaleDate
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 
and  (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleEndDate) < 0)
)
```

If you need the result in different rows use UNION:

```
Select  
(
Select  MIN(SaleStartDate) as MinSaleDate 
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 
and (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0)
) UNION
(
Select  MAX(SaleEndDate) as MaxSaleDate
from Sales 
where LessonID=1 
and  (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleEndDate) < 0)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

just put both on select like this:

```
Select  MIN(SaleStartDate) as MinSaleDate, 
        MAX(SaleEndDate) as MaxSaleDate
    from Sales 
where LessonID=1 and (DATEDIFF(day, 
                               CONVERT (char(10), 
                                        GETDATE(), 
                                        126),
                               Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0)
```

Comment: my 'where' clause is difference

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case you could just use a `CROSS JOIN` to get your result

```
SELECT MinSaleDate, MaxSaleDate
FROM
(
    Select  MIN(SaleStartDate) as MinSaleDate 
    from Sales 
    where LessonID = 1 and (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0)
),
(
    Select  MAX(SaleEndDate) as MaxSaleDate
    from Sales 
    where LessonID = 1 and  (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleEndDate) < 0)
);
```

For general case you could use:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleStartDate) > 0
            THEN SaleStartDate END) AS MinSaleDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (char(10), GETDATE(), 126), Sales.SaleEndDate) < 0
            THEN SaleEndDate END) AS MaxSaleDate
from Sales 
where LessonID = 1;
```

Comment: The case expression query is the way to go!